# How to create multiple columns in Pandas dataframe based on year

Tags: python, pandas

I have 10 years of hourly water level data that I'm trying to line up in separate columns based on year. The current format of the data is in two columns, one for the date and time (ex. 06/04/1989 06:00:00) of the reading and one for the water level. I'd like separate the data into individual columns based on year. I thought it was a straightforward task but with my limited experience in Pandas, I'm find it challenging. Any advice would be appreciated.

**Input:**

```
Obs_date         SLEV(metres)

31/12/1990 20:00    0.15
31/12/1990 21:00    0.14
31/12/1990 22:00    0.13
31/12/1990 23:00    0.16
...
31/12/1991 20:00    0.12
31/12/1991 21:00    0.13
31/12/1991 22:00    0.09
31/12/1991 23:00    0.08
```

**Output:**

```
Obs_date          1990   1991   
31-Dec 20:00:00   0.15   0.12
31-Dec 21:00:00   0.14   0.13
31-Dec 22:00:00   0.13   0.09
31-Dec 23:00:00   0.16   0.08
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First convert `Obs_date` to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), then create new column by [`Series.dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) and custom format by [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) and last pivoting by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with convert index to column by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) is used for remove column name:

```
df['Obs_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Obs_date'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
df['year'] = df['Obs_date'].dt.year
df['Obs_date'] = df['Obs_date'].dt.strftime('%d-%b %H:%M:%S')

df = df.pivot('Obs_date', 'year','SLEV(metres)').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
          Obs_date  1990  1991
0  31-Dec 20:00:00  0.15  0.12
1  31-Dec 21:00:00  0.14  0.13
2  31-Dec 22:00:00  0.13  0.09
3  31-Dec 23:00:00  0.16  0.08
```

Or is possible create Series `y` and `d` and reshape by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df['Obs_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Obs_date'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
y = df['Obs_date'].dt.year
d = df['Obs_date'].dt.strftime('%d-%b %H:%M:%S')

df = df.set_index([d, y])['SLEV(metres)'].unstack().reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
          Obs_date  1990  1991
0  31-Dec 20:00:00  0.15  0.12
1  31-Dec 21:00:00  0.14  0.13
2  31-Dec 22:00:00  0.13  0.09
3  31-Dec 23:00:00  0.16  0.08
```

---

If need processing data later and need correct order better is convert datetime to `DatetimeIndex` with some default year with `29.February`, e.g `2020`:

```
df['Obs_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Obs_date'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
y = df['Obs_date'].dt.year
d = pd.to_datetime(df['Obs_date'].dt.strftime('2020-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

df = df.set_index([d, y])['SLEV(metres)'].unstack().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
                     1990  1991
Obs_date                       
2020-12-31 20:00:00  0.15  0.12
2020-12-31 21:00:00  0.14  0.13
2020-12-31 22:00:00  0.13  0.09
2020-12-31 23:00:00  0.16  0.08
```